# Keeping elements together when wrapping

Tags: html, css

In my HTML, I have a series of input text fields with an image to the right of each input, which is used for deleting the contents of the field to the left of the image. When the browser is resized horizontally, I want the inputs along with their image to wrap and stay together.  Currently, if you resize the browser's width to a certain point, the input can appear on one line while its image wraps and appears on the line following it. Is there a way to always keep the input and image together when wrapping occurs?

```
<div style="display:block">
    <input type="text" id="inputEventDates" style="margin-right:17px" />
    <span><input type="text" /><img src="/images/icon_delete_16x16.png" class="ddelic" /></span>
    <span><input type="text" /><img src="/images/icon_delete_16x16.png" class="ddelic" /></span>
    <span><input type="text" /><img src="/images/icon_delete_16x16.png" class="ddelic" /></span>
    <span><input type="text" /><img src="/images/icon_delete_16x16.png" class="ddelic" /></span>
    <span><input type="text" /><img src="/images/icon_delete_16x16.png" class="ddelic" /></span>
    <span><input type="text" /><img src="/images/icon_delete_16x16.png" class="ddelic" /></span>
    <span><input type="text" /><img src="/images/icon_delete_16x16.png" class="ddelic" /></span>
    <span><input type="text" /><img src="/images/icon_delete_16x16.png" class="ddelic" /></span>
    <span><input type="text" /><img src="/images/icon_delete_16x16.png" class="ddelic" /></span>
    <span><input type="text" /><img src="/images/icon_delete_16x16.png" class="ddelic" /></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You will likely need to use fixed widths. This way your wrapping element wont resize below a certain point forcing the image to the next line. Or at least min-width's so that it stops resizing at a certain point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you change the display property to

```
{
display:inline;
}
```

Edit:
and what about: {overflow: hidden}   ?   does that work

Comment: `inline-block` is preferable....inline would make it difficult to style and position the elements if required later!!

Comment: Thanks, {display:inline-block;} works perfectly for me, when dividing text into columns and I want to keep e.g. a table together in one column.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using the same image. You could do better to simplify your markup by removing these images and use css instead.

*Demo*: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/pjqUW/**

*Markup*:

```
<span class="i"><input type="text" /></span>
<span class="i"><input type="text" /></span>
<span class="i"><input type="text" /></span>
...
```

*CSS*:

```
input { display: inline; }
span { white-space: nowrap; }
span.i:after {
    content: url(/images/icon_delete_16x16.png);
    display: inline;
    width: 16px; height: 16px;
}
```

You use `white-space: nowrap;` to keep it together.

*Note*: Can't use `:after` pseudo class on `input` itself because they are *replaced element* and `:after / :before` works only on *contained* elements. So, we use the available `span` instead.

*Update*: If you want to attach a click event handler to the images, then see this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/pjqUW/2/**

Comment: I need to have the images because the user will click on the image to delete the contents of the input field. Since you are setting the conent field, you can't attach an onclick event to the image.

Comment: @AndroidDev: furthermore, how only using the display as `inline` or `inline-block` will prevent wrapping? can you show me a fiddle with that?

Comment: what does :after does ?

Comment: In your JSFiddle, why didn't you just bind the click to the image instead of waiting for click, then go find the 'input' ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales: `:after` is a pseudo element. (Refer this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) In my example, I cannot bind the click directly to image because pseudo elements cannot be targetted. So, I am targeting the container and `.not`ting out the `input`.

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales: Yes. You are right. Images can have a click handler. But again, in my particular example, am not using images at all.

Comment: Can you please make or provide an example of that ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales: The example is already there in my answer! http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/pjqUW/2/